# python return - "name not defined"

Tags: python, function, variables, return

I'm trying to get this script to write information into a basic text file. I'm still learning python.

The problem lies here:

```
file_text = """%s SHOOT DETAILS\n
Number of shoots:\t %s
Maximum range:\t %s
Number of firers:\t %s
Number of lanes active:\t %s
Number of details:\t %s
Troops per detail:\t %s
\n 
RANGE STAFF
Ammo NCO:\t %s
Medical Supervisor:\t %s
IC Butts:\t %s""" % (shoot_name, number_of_shoots, max_range, number_of_firers, number_of_lanes, number_of_details, size_of_details, ammo_nco, medical_supervisor, ic_butts)
```

The error message:
NameError: name 'number_of_details' is not defined

The above is (supposedly) written into a file with this:

```
def generatedocument():
    file = open(file_name, 'w')
    file.write(file_text)
    os.startfile(file_name)
```

However I did define it earlier in the following function:

```
def detailformation():
    number_of_details = number_of_firers / number_of_lanes
    return number_of_details
```

Identical problems occur for the size_of_details, defined:

```
def detailsizer():
    size_of_details = number_of_firers / detailformation()
    return size_of_details
```

And also with the range staff chooser function, sometimes it gives me a similar error. They come from this function that randomly selects them from a list:

```
def range_staff():
    print "\n"
    ammo_nco = (random.choice(fiveplatoon))
    print "Ammo NCO: "+ammo_nco
    fiveplatoon.remove(ammo_nco)
    medical_supervisor = (random.choice(fiveplatoon))
    print "Medical supervisor: "+medical_supervisor
    fiveplatoon.remove(medical_supervisor)
    ic_butts = (random.choice(fiveplatoon))
    print "IC Butts/Console: "+ic_butts
    fiveplatoon.remove(ic_butts)
    return range_staff
```

It seems like I'm missing something fundamental here. How can I get python to recognise?

Comment: You need to actually _call_ your functions...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The variables only exist in the scope you declare them

```
def fun():
    x = 5
    return x

>>> x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    x
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

If you want to use the `return` value from a function, then call the function and assign it to such a variable

```
>>> x = fun()
>>> x
5
```

Comment: Correct. And if you want to work with multiple return values just seperate them with commas.

Answer (score 1):

Call your functions in order to get the value they return

```
size_of_details = detailsizer()
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a **scope** issue. Variables declared inside functions are only defined within that function. To fix it, put the declaration of the variable on the same **scope** as where it is used. See below for the sample code

```
number_of_details = 0

def detailformation():
    number_of_details = number_of_firers / number_of_lanes
    return number_of_details

file_text = """%s SHOOT DETAILS\n
Number of shoots:\t %s
Maximum range:\t %s
Number of firers:\t %s
Number of lanes active:\t %s
Number of details:\t %s
Troops per detail:\t %s
\n 
RANGE STAFF
Ammo NCO:\t %s
Medical Supervisor:\t %s
IC Butts:\t %s""" % (shoot_name, number_of_shoots, max_range, number_of_firers, number_of_lanes, number_of_details, size_of_details, ammo_nco, medical_supervisor, ic_butts)
```

Note that this is just a quick solution (putting the variable on the global scope).