# Return variables from one function to use in another with python

Tags: python, scope-chain

I don't know why this isn't working

```html
from bs4 import *
import time
import pandas as pd
import pickle
import html5lib
from requests_html import HTMLSession

s = HTMLSession()
url = "https://cryptoli.st/lists/fixed-supply"


def get_data(url):
    r = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    return soup
    
def get_next_page(soup):
    page = soup.find('ul', {'class': 'pager'})
    if not page.find('a', {'class': 'btn btn-default current disabled'}):
        url = 'https://cryptoli.st/lists/fixed-supply' + \
            str(page.find('li', {'class': 'paginate_button'}).find(
                'a')[{'class': 'btn btn-default next'}])
        return url
    else:
        return


get_data(url)
print(get_next_page(soup))
```

I have seen other scripts that return variables from one function to use in another but this keeps saying "soup" is not defined. Then if I make soup a global variable then I get the error that page is a Nonetype and I can't call the .find attribute off it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You forgot to assign the result of `get_data` to `data`.

Comment: You haven't defined a variable named `data`.

Comment: This shouldn't be saying `soup` is not defined, it should say `data` is not defined.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python return - "name not defined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35242714/python-return-name-not-defined)

Comment: Any ideas on why page.find is returning this nonetype error? or how to fix this?
This is the error it's giving me:

if not page.find('a', {'class': 'btn btn-default current disabled'}):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last line for `print(get_next_page(data))` is running the function `get_next_page` with the parameter `data` passed in. However, `data` is never defined, and so it passes in None. So then inside of `get_next_page`, it assigns `soup = None`. Then you are running everything else on `None`.

In the second-to-bottom line you need to do `data = get_data(url)`, and then when you call `get_next_page(data))`, data will be equal to the `soup` that you returned from the first function.

Also, you probably need that `s = HTMLSession()` to either be inside of the `get_url` function, or pass it in like you do `url`

Comment: Sorry I just edited it. When I run the get_next_page function soup should be passed in there. I changed the variable names

Answer (score 2):

This is what you are doing.

```
def define_soup():
    soup = 'yummy'
    return soup 
def eat():
    return soup
define_soup() 
print(eat())
```

`soup` sure is defined in `define_soup()`, but it is local to that one function. No other function can use it. So assuming that because we have called `define_soup()` therefor we can use it in `eat()` is wrong. Instead you can make `soup` global or store the returned value of `define_soup()` in a variable.

**using global**

```
def define_soup():
    global soup
    soup = 'yummy'
    return soup 
def eat():
    return soup
define_soup() 
print(eat())
```

**storing define_soup() output in var**

```
def define_soup():
    soup = 'yummy'
    return soup 
def eat(soup):
    return soup
sp = define_soup() 
print(eat(sp))
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

get_data(url) function returns a variable but is not stored in anything. So you can do

data = get_data(url)
print(get_next_page(data))